# How to copy all the formatting information of the current selection?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is it possible to copy all the formatting information from Selection?

I've seen [this page](http://www.excelhowto.com/macros/formatting-a-range-of-cells-in-excel-vba/), which lists all the different format properties of a Range, but is it possible to get all of them at once and store them to be used later?

Something like:

```
Public formatting As Collection
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set formatting = Selection.allFormatting
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I recorded a macro while I selected one cell, chose the format painter to pick up its formatting and applied it to another cell.  Result:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Selection.Copy
    Range("E9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

And it seems to work, but once only; that is, if you want to apply the same formatting to another cell, you have to Select it then Selection.Copy again before applying.

All that selecting is bad for the eyes and not necessary, though.  This is better:

```
Range("E7").Copy
Range("E9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```